# When in-class member initialization is mandatory

Tags: c++

When in-class member initialization is strictly mandatory?

Rules for in-class member initialization are complex and we could avoid that by using Ctor initializer list for non-static members and define static members outside the class. IMHO, this also separates declaration and definition more.

Comment: I can't think of anything that you can't initialize in a constructor's initialization list when it can be initialized using in-class member initialization.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you want, you can write an answer. I will wait to see if there are more comments on this questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static constant member must have an initialiser if it's used in-class in a context where a constant expression is required. For example,

```
struct S {
  static const int N = 4;
  int arr[N]; // okay
};

const int S::N;

struct T {
  static const int N;
  int arr[N]; // error
};

const int T::N = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, when using C-style arrays, in-class static const member initialization is needed. Thanks!